# finding the sum of the array when size is not given by the user,

Tags: c, c++11

Input
The i-th line of the input contains an integer ai (0 ≤ a ≤ 1000) — the i-th element of the array. The size of the array is between 1 and 10, inclusive. Note that the size of the array is not given explicitly!

Output
Output a single integer — the sum of the elements of the array.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stackoverflow.com is not a free code writing service.

Comment: You need to show your code if you want to know what is wrong with it.

Comment: Aside from the fact that on the face of it, it seems like you are asking someone to do your assignment for you. You have added tags for 3 different languages, all of which would have different answers. Which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is your code?

But i have an example, if you have an integer array like below:

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 5, 3, 8, 5};
```

You can easily find the number of elements in your array by using sizeof().

```
int numberOfElement = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);
```

And now you can calculate the sum of array with this size.